# What's the easiest way to generate a link to edit a given entry in Craft?

Tags: templating

Assuming I am fetching an entry like so:

`{% set profile = craft.entries.id(8268).one %}`

What is the easiest way to generate a link that allows you to edit that entry in Craft? I know you can do the following:

`{{ siteUrl ~ 'admin/entries/profiles/' ~ profile.id }}`

But surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`profile.cpEditUrl` is what you're looking for.

Comment: So easy, thank you!